# How can I get the value of select tag in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning the Vue JS and I have a problem.

I want to get the value of the selected option.

But I can't.

I tried to search on Google but I can't find.

This is my sample code.

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    changeOption: function(){
      console.log('How can I get the value of selected option?');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<select v-on:change="changeOption()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `v-model` directive.

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    selectedOption : null
  },
  methods: {
    changeOption: function(){
       console.log(this.selectedOption);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<select v-model="selectedOption" v-on:change="changeOption(event)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Another approach is to pass the event to the `function` and use `event.target.value` in order to find out the value of the `select` element.

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    changeOption: function(e){
       console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<select v-on:change="changeOption(event)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Two changes in your code :-

1. Replace  `<select v-on:change="changeOption()">`
   to `<select v-on:change="changeOption">`
2. changeOption:

   function(event){
             console.log(event.target.value);
             //console.log('How can I get the value of selected option?');
           }

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    changeOption: function(event){
      console.log(event.target.value);
      //console.log('How can I get the value of selected option?');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<select v-on:change="changeOption">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```